# Link to a root controller from area controller in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

How can I link to one of my root controllers from one of my areas?

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Action", "Page", new {area = "root", name = "Admin"}); %>
```

This gives me an error:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

I have a controller named `Page`in a folder named `Admin` in my root controller collection.
I can reach this controller by typing \Admin\Page.

This is how I registered the route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

I was hoping I could address the "Admin" route using this syntax in my view, but that did not work. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new { area = "" }); %>
```

Comment: Lol.. it actually was that easy. I was just confused by some other blog saying `root` was the "code" for root. But the correct way is blank area. Thank you.